# Json.NET deserializing nested object ignores JsonProperty.Required

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net, json-deserialization

When deserializing a JSON object with nested objects, with a required property on one of the nested objects, Deserialize does not throw an Exception. But if I add the JsonProperty.Required decoration to the base object, it does (as I'd expect). This happens when the input string is the entirely wrong type, but is properly formatted JSON.

So, the problematic input is "{\"Errors\":[\"This is an error\"]}" (which is the response from a webservice, either it's an array of error messages like this, or it's a properly serialized UserInformationRequest). 
Code to clarify:

Base Object JsonProperty functioning properly:

```
    public class UserInformation
    {
        public string ID;
        ...
        public string LoginName;
        ...
    }

    public class UserInformationRequest
    {
        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public string TimeStamp;
        public UserInformation User;
    }
    ...
    public static UserInformationRequest GetUserInformationRequestFromString(string userInformation)
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserRequestInformation>(userInformation);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //exception thrown when userInformation.TimeStamp is null, as expected
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Nested JsonProperty not functioning properly:

```
    public class UserInformation
    {
        public string ID;
        ...
        [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]
        public string LoginName;
        ...
    }

    public class UserInformationRequest
    {
        public string TimeStamp;
        public UserInformation User;
    }
    ...
    public static UserInformationRequest GetUserInformationRequestFromString(string userInformation)
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserRequestInformation>(userInformation);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //never gets here - no exception thrown if userInformation.User.LoginName is null
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Given this, when attempting to deserialize the Errors array into the UserInformationRequest, an exception is properly thrown if there is a JsonProperty on the base object, but it is never thrown if the nested object contains a JsonProperty.

Working dotnetfiddles demonstrating the issue:
JsonProperty on base object: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qvyPfP
JsonProperty on nested object: https://dotnetfiddle.net/M3F0rb

Comment: Could you show the "userInformation" json string received as parameter in the "GetUserInformationRequestFromString" method please ?

Comment: @emkayultra, in what version(s) of .Net and Json.Net are you seeing this issue?

Comment: @JonLopezGarcia - first example: "{\"TimeStamp\":null,\"User\":{\"ID\":12345,\"LoginName\":\"username\"}}"}  AND second example:
"{\"TimeStamp\":\"2017-07-29 10:31:53\",\"User\":{\"ID\":12345,\"LoginName\":null}}"

Comment: @AlDass - .NET 4.5, Json.NET 10.0.3

Comment: I'm updating the question, because after digging it's a little more complicated than that.

Comment: There's two dotnetfiddle links at the bottom to demonstrate what I'm saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you also mark, your `User` property in the `UserInformationRequest` class with the `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` attribute, the deserializer seems to look inside the `UserInformation` for the `LoginName` member to be not `null` as requested.

[Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AsXyv8) you have your second example with the attribute on the `User` property

Comment: That looks like it does sort of address the issue.  However, what if I don't want User to be required, but if User does happen to be supplied, then it has to have LoginName

Comment: Well, if we consider carefully, it is exactly what happens. If you supply a **User** property and the required attribute is on the **LoginName** property, an exception will be raised. See [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Mso1H6).

If you don't supply nothing about an **User** property in the json string, the deserializer will completely ignore the field in the class. 

If you don't want the behavior to be so, and force the deserializer to look after an **User** property in the json, it means that you want the field to be fill out (in other words, to be required). Use required attribute

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for your help and clarification.  Marking your answer as "the" answer.